# What is the Kotlin equivalent for Dart's List.expand() method?

Tags: kotlin

In Dart, List.expand() allows mapping each element of the existing List into zero, one, or multiple elements, and then assemble them as a new Iterable. Such as,

```
var a=[1,2,3];
var b = a.expand((i)=>List.generate(i,(_)=>i.toString())).toList();
print(b.toString());
//Output: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Basically an enhanced `map()` function allows "one to many" mapping

What is the Kotlin equivalent if I want to do the same? I failed to find corresponding method in Kotlin collections.

Comment: Do you mean `flatMap` (one to many mapping) - https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html

Comment: flatMap is the right answer, but it took me a while to understand it.  the key is that the lambda must return a list/iteratior ,  even if 0 , or 1 entry  e.g. listOf(1,2,3,4).flatMap{. listOf( it , it + 1 , it * 1000)} = 1,2,10000,2,3,2000,3,4,3000,4,5,4000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3) // listOf(1, 2, 3)
    val b = a.flatMap({i ->
        List(i) { i }
    })

    println(b)
}

> [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

`List(i) { i }` is [a cool comprehension](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html) for your list generator. [Play online](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/prcc9bscliguk4tjlgb1kjn7kj/cfqve9bsrbcplb4baq0t9qtrdn)  with this code on https://try.kotlinlang.org!